# Learn Python the Hard Way ex35 Bear Room

Tags: python, while-loop, branch, python-3.5

I'm trying to understand a particular piece of code in the Learn Python the Hard Way example 35 problem before I move on.

True to the book's request, I've been writing a comment above just about every line (or block) of code to break down what's going on so I can test my understanding of what's going on.

I'm having a little trouble with some of the branching logic being used in a while loop, of which I will post (I'm posting a modified version that should help show what I've been doing to make sure I'm understanding things).

```
def bear_room():
    print("There is a bear here.")
    print("The bear has a bunch of honey.")
    print("The fat bear is in front of another door.")
    print("How are you going to move the bear?")
    bear_moved = False # default status of bear


while True:
    bear_loop_counter = 0
    choice = input("bear room input>  ")

    if choice == "take honey":
        dead("The bear looks at you and slaps your face off.")

    elif choice == "taunt bear" and not bear_moved:
        print("The bear has moved from the door.")
        print("You can go through it now.")
        bear_loop_counter += 1
        print("The bear room loop has iterated",bear_loop_counter, "time.")
        bear_moved = True
    elif choice == "taunt bear" and bear_moved:
        dead("The bear gets pissed off and chews your leg off.")
    elif choice == "open door" and bear_moved:
        gold_room()
    else:
        print("I got no idea what that means")
```

As you can see, I implemented a few things for debugging, including changing the input prompt to something that shows me what block of code I'm dealing with, and a counter that shows how many passes through the loop I've made.

I'm trying to understand the snippet of code that says:

```
elif choice == "taunt bear" and not bear_moved
```

I understand that this while loop is basically waiting for you to enter into one of the branches that will exit the loop (the dead() or one of the other_room() bits).  I also know that the default "status" of the bear is "not_moved" and that the "taunt_bear" branch will change the status of the bear.  I'm not getting the "and not" part of that segment of code though.

My understanding is that:

```
bear_moved = False
```

Which seems to me would mean that the "and not bear_moved" would be interpreted as "and not bear_moved(False)" which in turn would read "and bear_moved(True)" if you were to simplify that logic.  So, written in plain english, "If your choice is to taunt the bear, AND the bear IS MOVED, execute some print statements... increment the counter, etc."  Obviously that's not how the code works.  I can see from my counter and just running the program that the "and not" statement is not working how I just explained.

I guess I'm operating on the assumption that bear_moved is SET by ME to False when I wrote the code.  I could understand it doing what it does if bear_moved is assumed by Python to be True or something.  I'm thinking:

```
bear_moved = False
```

Therefore:

```
not bear_moved == True
```

That's the point I'm seeking clarification on.

Thanks in advance.

Comment: No, why would it mean that? `and not bear_moved` translates simply as `and the value of bear_moved is false`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here, `not bear_moved` means `bear_moved` is `False`.

Quoting [the python doc](https://docs.python.org/3/reference/expressions.html#boolean-operations):

> The operator not yields True if its argument is false, False otherwise.

Comment: This is what I'm having a hard time grasping.  It makes a lot more sense to me to write it as "... and bear_moved == False" instead of "... and not bear_moved".  It's driving me insane that I can't intuitively understand this - like I KNOW this is a simple concept but it just won't click.

Comment: @Anthony If it helps : what you are saying in your question is exactly what happens ("I'm thinking `bear_moved = False` Therefore : `not bear_moved == True`").

Answer (score 1):

For the branch to progress the statement needs to be true and true under its conditions.

If you typed taunt bear that signals first true.

In second part (other side of the 'and') 'not bear_moved' this must evaluate to true also. Boolean states that if bear is false and 'not' is used this becomes true. Which basically reads bear = true .

Now you have 2 trues  for the branch to progress.

Think the confusion comes from thinking the bear has moved. In reality this is just a variable which you store the word false in until you change it. All the branch wants is a clean house of trues to progress. Not changes false to true.

Comment: Hey there - Just wanted to say I have (thankfully) long since moved past this problem! Thanks for adding some more context in case anyone else is stuck on this in the future.